# Get a collection of child positions for a given parent position

Tags: c#, performance, linq, iteration, linq-expressions

I am trying to get a complete tree in a single loop using an iterative function. For instance, this is what I have:

```
var someVariable = GetAllChildPositions(posId) //Method called from a console method.



public ICollection<Position> GetAllChildPositions(int posId)
{
    ICollection<Position> posCollection = new Collection<Position>();
    posCollection= GetChildPos(posId,posCollection);
    return posCollection;
}

public ICollection<Position> GetChildPos(int posId, ICollection<Position> posCollection) 
{
    var posObject= serviceRepo.Position.GetById(posId);
    posCollection.Add(posObject);
    if (serviceRepo.Position.GetAll().Where(x => x.ParentPosId == posId).Any())
    {
        var childPositions = serviceRepo.Position().GetAll().Where(x => x.ParentPosId == posId);
        foreach (var childPos in childPositions )
        {
            GetChildRows(childPos.Id, posCollection);
        }
    }
    return posCollection;
}
```

I am trying to get a list/collection child positions for a given parent position Id. This method works quite well and gets the job done albeit a little slowly. I am interested in knowing if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Please ensure that you have posted real working code, or an excerpt of real working code. Obfuscation is discouraged; see [ask].

Comment: The only thing I have obfuscated in the code is the variable names. Apart from that rest all code are actually that is present on the testing server which is undergoing testing. Can you point me where the code is broken or not written ?  I am adding some updates to the code let me know if it helps.

Comment: I had closed the question because `DatabsaeCall()` was a clear sign that this was fake code. Thanks for editing; I have reopened the question.

Comment: @t3chb0t: I think his code does work structurally - he passes in reference to a collection to which objects are added and then he passes that reference back. I agree that it's ugly and not necessary but it still works. [And `Collection<T>` does exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ChrisWue ok, my bad, sorry ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t It definitely is an ugly piece of code, no debates there. My point in posting was to learn how best I can optmise code to look better and also perform better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Position` and `Position()` in your code is the same and you supposed to call `GetChildPos` instead of `GetChildRows` in the inner loop then your code can be significantly simplified:

```
var someVariable = GetChildPos(posId).ToList();

public IEnumerable<Position> GetChildPos(int posId)
{
    yield return serviceRepo.Position.GetById(posId);

    foreach (var pos in serviceRepo.Position().GetAll()
                                              .Where(x => x.ParentPosId == posId)
                                              .SelectMany(x => GetChildPos(x.Id)))
    {
        yield return pos;
    }
}
```

Also it can improve performance because in your original code you do this instructions

```
serviceRepo.Position().GetAll().Where(x => x.ParentPosId == posId)
```

two times that can cause slowing down if some method in this chain is not lazy and executes heavy code even for `Any()`.

Comment: This can be even further improved by passing the actual `Position` object as parameter instead of having to call `GetById` every single time. Just needs a wrapper methods which calls `GetById` for the root once

Comment: @ChrisWue Yes, agree with you. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Thank you for that. While your code is way cleaner than what I have done, it would seems DawidP is way faster than the yield method. I am gonna try and follow @ChrisWue suggestion and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Did you test that my code slower? I don't see anything that can make it to run slowly than solution of @DawidP. He use LINQ query as well and also has the same query repeated twice as in your code :)

Comment: @Maxim, that's what made it so strange. I am checking it further to make sure I did not make stupid mistakes

Comment: @Maxim sorry it was outer code that was making the whole process slow. The individual piece  is faster . Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

I think @Maxim's answer should yield a reasonable improvement and as mentioned in the comment you could pass in the `Position` object directly saving a call to `GetById` every single time.

One consideration not mentioned: If `GetAll` actually returns all `Position`s in a non-lazy fashion then you'd be better off putting the `Positions` into a `Dictionary<int, Position>` keyed by their id and performing the search in a single loop by either using a stack or a queue (depth first vs breadth first)

Comment: It did improve compared to my method but falls short of DawidP method. I am going to try your suggestion of passing the object and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

What really would speed this up would be to store the result of `serviceRepo.Position().GetAll()` into a variable and pass this as an argument to the desired method. In its current state you query for the "root" item at least one time(`.Any()`) but only if there aren't any children.

If there are children, you make this call a second time and for each child you do at least one more call.
So for a tree like this

```
      A
     / \
    B   C
   / \
  D   E
     / \
    F   G
```

This call would happen 10 times.

---

If we would integrate this into @Maxim's answer we would get

```
public IEnumerable<Position> GetChildPos(int posId)
{
    var positions = serviceRepo.Position().GetAll()
    return GetChildPos(posId, positions);
}  

public IEnumerable<Position> GetChildPos(int posId, IEnumerable<SomeObject> positions)
{
    yield return serviceRepo.Position.GetById(posId);

    foreach (var pos in positions.Where(x => x.ParentPosId == posId)
                                 .SelectMany(x => GetChildPos(x.Id, positions)))
    {
        yield return pos;
    }
}
```